# excel xlsx file parsing - using koogra

Tags: c#, excel, .net-4.0, xml-parsing, text-parsing

After trying few packages with git hub, and trying to parse/process this quite a large excel document. 
Each one of methods I was trying  throw  exception on `out of memory`.

I was google *ing* some more and found this GNU Library named `koogra` which seems to be only one I could see fit for the job,  couldn't bother too much and continue on searching as I am running out of time for this part of the project .

The code I have got by now is working pass the part of the "out of memory" issue,

so only thing left is how do I properly parse an Excel Document so it will be possible to extract say a kind of dictionary collection key is one column and value is another.

[this is the file in question](http://www.seobook.com/learn-seo/top10000sept.xlsx)

this is the code i have so far

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "tst.xlsx");
Net.SourceForge.Koogra.Excel2007.Workbook xcel = new Net.SourceForge.Koogra.Excel2007.Workbook(path);
var ss = xcel.GetWorksheets();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

found it by some more .... google *ing*... 
first row for usage on 2007 (`xlsx`)

second row is for `xls` version

```
        Net.SourceForge.Koogra.IWorkbook genericWB = Net.SourceForge.Koogra.WorkbookFactory.GetExcel2007Reader("tst.xlsx");

        //genericWB = Net.SourceForge.Koogra.WorkbookFactory.GetExcelBIFFReader("some.xls");

        Net.SourceForge.Koogra.IWorksheet genericWS = genericWB.Worksheets.GetWorksheetByIndex(0);

        for (uint r = genericWS.FirstRow; r <= genericWS.LastRow; ++r)
        {
            Net.SourceForge.Koogra.IRow row = genericWS.Rows.GetRow(r);

            for (uint c = genericWS.FirstCol; c <= genericWS.LastCol; ++c)
            {
                // raw value
                Console.WriteLine(row.GetCell(c).Value);

                // formatted value
                Console.WriteLine(row.GetCell(c).GetFormattedValue());
            }
        }
```

i hope that i helped anyone else out there that encountered same "out of memory" issue ... '
enjoy

**a small update** to the code above

OK.. I Have played with this a little , so as far as it is related to the content of the file 
the chart is ranked based on `Unique IP` and the current code is

```
            //place source file within your current:
            //project directory\bin\debug and you should find extracted file next to the source file 
            var pathtoRead = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "tst.xlsx");
            var pathtoWrite = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "tst.txt");

            Net.SourceForge.Koogra.IWorkbook genericWB = Net.SourceForge.Koogra.WorkbookFactory.GetExcel2007Reader(pathtoRead);
            Net.SourceForge.Koogra.IWorksheet genericWS = genericWB.Worksheets.GetWorksheetByIndex(0);
            StringBuilder SbXls = new StringBuilder();
            for (uint r = genericWS.FirstRow; r <= genericWS.LastRow; ++r)
            {
                Net.SourceForge.Koogra.IRow row = genericWS.Rows.GetRow(r);
                string LineEnding = string.Empty;
                for (uint ColCount = genericWS.FirstCol; ColCount <= genericWS.LastCol; ++ColCount)
                {

                    var formated = row.GetCell(ColCount).GetFormattedValue();
                    if (ColCount == 1)
                        LineEnding = Environment.NewLine;
                    else if (ColCount == 0)
                        LineEnding = "\t";
                    if (ColCount > 1 == false)
                        SbXls.Append(string.Concat(formated, LineEnding));
                }
            }
            File.WriteAllText(pathtoWrite, SbXls.ToString());
```